# How to find $v_4$ such that $span\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}=\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am in trouble with these exercise: Consider the vectors $v_1=(1, 0, 0, 1), v_2=(2, h, h, 2), v_3=(1, 1+h, 2h +1, 1)$ with $h\in\mathbb{R}$. Determine the dimension of the subspace $S$ generated by $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ by varying $h\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, choosen $h\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $dim(S) =3$, find $v_4$ such that $span\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\} = \mathbb{R}^4$.

In order to find the dimension of the generated subspace $S$ by varying $h\in\mathbb{R}$, I evaluate

$\begin{vmatrix}
1 &2&1\\
0&h &1+h\\
0& h&2h+1\\
1&2&1
\end{vmatrix}$

I observe that $rank(A) = 3$ for all $h\neq 0$ and if $h=0, rank(A) = 2$. So (I guess) the answer to the first question is that $dim(S) =3$ for all $h\neq 0$.

How to proceed to find $v_4$ such that $span\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}=\mathbb{R}^4$?
Could anyone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $v_{4}$? You only have $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W$ be linear space of finite dimension $n$ with $\{w_1, \dots , w_n\}$ a basis of $W$.

It is a theorem that for a linear subspace $V$ spanned by $\{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$ with $m \lt n$, you can pickup $w \in \{w_1, \dots , w_n\}$ such that $\{v_1, \dots, v_m, w\}$ is linearly independent.

So in your case, take the canonical basis $\{e_1, \dots e_4\}$. If $h \neq 0$, $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ are linearly independent. You can pick up one of the vectors $e_i$ of the canonical basis in a way to get a basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,e_i\}$ of $\mathbb R^4$. Just test them one after the other... one will work!

In fact,

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 &2&1\\
0 & 0&h &1+h\\
0 & 0& h&2h+1\\
0& 1&2&1
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
0&h &1+h\\
0& h&2h+1\\
1&2&1
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
h &1+h\\
h&2h+1
\end{vmatrix} = h^2 \neq 0$$

So you already win with $e_1$ and $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,e_1\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My attempt to find the right $h$ to determine $dim(S)$ is right, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: Sorry, could you give me a reference for the theorem you mentioned above? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @C.Bishop [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma#:~:text=The%20Steinitz%20exchange%20lemma%20is,the%20German%20mathematician%20Ernst%20Steinitz.)